# Pokitdok / X12 - Check on eligibility batch data

Tags: edi, x12

Maybe someone has experience with [pokitdok](https://pokitdok.com)
I want to check on eligibility batch data, but this X12 query will return data with one item.

```
const data = {x12: `ISA*03*0123456789*01*1234567890*30*000000005      *30*12345          *131031*1147*^*00501*000000907*1*T*:~
GS*HS*000000005*12345*20131031*1147*1*X*005010X279A1~
ST*270*0001*005010X279A1~
  BHT*0022*13*10001234*20131031*1147~
  HL*1**20*1~
  NM1*PR*2*MOCKPAYER*****PI*MOCKPAYER~
  HL*2*1*21*1~
  NM1*1P*2*POKITDOK, INC.*****XX*1912301953~
  HL*3*2*22*0~
  TRN*1*930000000000*9800000004~
  NM1*IL*1*Doe*Jane****MI*W000000001~
  DMG*D8*19700101~
  DTP*291*D8*20131031~
  NM1*IL*1*Doe2*Jane****MI*W000000002~
  DMG*D8*19700202~
  DTP*291*D8*20131031~
SE*13*0001~
GE*1*1~IEA*1*000000907~`}
```

Somebody can help me with X12 loop?

Comment: Download EDI Notepad to help you with the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you've got a strict obligation or other compelling reason to continue using the raw X12 format in the implementation you're working on, I'd highly recommend moving to the simplified JSON format that PokitDok provides. (You can view the various format options [here](https://platform.pokitdok.com/documentation/v4/?#raw-x12-support).) You can use the `async` parameter to "batch" by streaming in multiple calls (one per individual), and you can either capture the resulting `activity_id` values and retrieve the responses later through the [Activities API](https://platform.pokitdok.com/documentation/v4/?#activities) or provide a [`callback_url`](https://platform.pokitdok.com/documentation/v4/?#api-callbacks) so that the results get posted to you without needing to poll the system.

The alternative at the moment is to transmit a properly formatted batch X12 file to us via SFTP (not via API, unfortunately), at which time we'll break it up and turn it into individual activities anyway. Hope that helps!

Disclosure: I'm a Solutions Engineer for PokitDok.

Comment: Hi D Richardson, thank you for your reply.
Can I ask you to clarify the question?
So I can use [eligibility](https://platform.pokitdok.com/documentation/v4/?#eligibility) for several subscribers (users) using `async` parameter?
curl -XPOST -d '{
    "members": [{
        "first_name": "Eric1",
        "last_name": "Brovko1",
        "id": "W000000001"
    }, {
        "first_name": "Eric2",
        "last_name": "Brovko2",
        "id": "W000000002"
    }],
   "parameters": {"async": true},
    "trading_partner_id": "MOCKPAYER"
}' https://platform.pokitdok.com/api/v4/eligibility/

Comment: Hi @Eric - you would need to submit each subscriber's information in a separate call, but you can absolutely fire off multiple calls quickly. The `async` parameter just means you'll be immediately handed an `activity_id` rather than waiting until the transaction is complete, so you're not blocked.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
I have to ask you the last question - Can we send multiple memberIds in one call?

Comment: @Eric No, you cannot send multiple member IDs in a single call to our RESTful JSON API. The solution I recommended above is a great alternative to doing that. If you must use a single file, you'll need to be able to properly format the X12 batch file and we'll need to set up a secure connection for file submission and pickup outside of the API. 
(This is no longer about the original question regarding X12 formatting, but instead about the delivery mechanism for the functionality, so perhaps we should move this conversation off of Stack Overflow.)

Comment: Got it!
Thank you so much for your answers and for your time!